# Do not show excerpt in post content

Tags: themes, excerpt, single, read-more

I need to keep showing excerpt in list of articles on my index, while, not showing it on single post page.

I am using more tag to manually define excerpts.

Is there a way to trim excerpt from the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the more tag to manually define excerpts. There's a separate input field for that. If it's not visible, go to "screen options" in the upper right corner of the edit screen to enable it.

What exactly is shown on your single and archive pages depends on your theme. There is no general way to address this. But if you use the excerpt field for what it is meant to do, any decent theme will pick it up and display the excerpt on archive pages and the post (where you have removed the excerpt) on the single page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - That's exactly what I was looking for. Even easier, I thought I'd need custom filter or something like that. I am outputting content by the_content() function in my theme, so all is looking good now. Appreciate your help!